# usage of procure in [procure a movie contract, a deal, a good price, data and a loan]

Tags: vocabulary

According to Merriam-Webster Dictionary, to procure means to get possession of something or to get something by particular care and effort.

I have made up the sentences below.

(1) As a new actor, I find it difficult to **procure my first movie contract**.

(2) I have been losing money in my business. I'm hoping to **procure a deal** soon before I have to close it permanently.

(3) Houses are very expensive these days. I have been looking at houses and comparing their prices. With a limited budget, I have not been able to **procure a good price**.

(4) Scientists have **procured large amounts** of data related to global warming.

(5) I didn't have much success in **procuring a bank loan** last year.

If the way I used the verb was wrong, how do you use it?

Comment: They are fine, but I would usually say: get a deal. procure is a formal word for get in the sense of obtain.

Comment: The register of the word procure is high; get is colloquial or low register.

Comment: As Lambie says, there's nothing wrong with *get*. You might consider using *[secure](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/secure)* where you want to say, *Succeed in obtaining (something), especially with difficulty.* For (4), *gathered* or *collected together* might be better.

Comment: I would say "Scientists have assembled (or collected) large amounts of data". They have made measurements and collected information themselves; _procured_ sounds as though they had bought the data from elsewhere.

Comment: @Kate Bunting: So would I, dammit! I *knew* a word was eluding me :-)